# How do I block my torrent client from sending data in a certain time range?

Tags: osx-lion, firewall, bittorrent

I'd like to block my torrent client on Mac OS X Lion from accessing Internet, from 6pm to 2am, so that it doesn't slow down my connection while I need it.

Is there a way I could do that using some sort of software or firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Bittorrent client with scheduling, for example [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/).

Set speed limit mode to 0kb up and down and schedule it for 6pm to 2am. It will continue running, but no transfers will actually happen.

[image]